# Custom dynamic fields - SimpleXMLElement in model and data info fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, jform, form, model

Good morning,

I have a question. I create my own fields in my own component. I'm using the "SimpleXMLElement" class. The form generates via getForm work perfectly:

```
$newfieldset = new SimpleXMLElement('<fieldset></fieldset>');
$newfieldset->addAttribute('name', 'case_customfields');

foreach($customfields as $customfield) 
{
    $field = $newfieldset->addChild('field');
    $field->addAttribute('name', $customfield->field_name . '-' . $customfield->id);
    $field->addAttribute('type', $customfield->field_type);
    $field->addAttribute('default', $customfield->field_default_value);
    $field->addAttribute('label', $customfield->field_label);
    $field->addAttribute('description', $customfield->field_description);

}

$form->setField($newfieldset);

return $form;
```

I also modified the getItem function, which returns values for my own fields:

```
    $customfields_value = $this->getCustomFieldsValues($pk);

    foreach($customfields_value as $customfield_value) 
    {
        $singleCustomField = $this->getSingleCustomFields($customfield_value->custom_fields_id);
        $field_id = $singleCustomField['id'];
        $field_name = $singleCustomField['field_name'];

        $field = $field_name . '-' . $field_id;
        $item->$field = $customfield_value->value;

    }

    return $item;
```

Work perfectly too.

The problem is that in the edit form I do not see custom values. If I create a static form in XML (models / forms), the data is. For fields created via "SimpleXMLElement" - data is not in the form.

Of course, I can load data into the form via the "SimpleXMLElement" class in getForm, but that seems to me to be a bad way.

Where do I make a mistake? And thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

My fault. Wrong order. Corectly is:
1. First - create form and transform to SimpleXMLElement

> $formXml = new
>   SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents(JPATH_COMPONENT.'path to xml
>   file'));

2. Add children element to form
3. Convert SimpleXMLElement to new XML
4. New XML (with children) as $form
5. Return $form